# Is it possible to write two anchor programs in one root on Solana playground? if so please assist with an example

Tags: anchor

I am trying to deploy an anchor program via Solana CLI using anchor deploy but either it keeps getting timed out or exceeds max retries. However, when I deploy on Solana playground it is always successful.

I have an NFT typescript app, with a staking program and a reward program, implementing the Cross Program Invocation (CPI) concept. The program folder structure was created using 'anchor init nft_ts_app'. I would like to implement the same folder structure on Solana Playground IDE.

Now the challenge I'm facing is creating a second program on Solana playground with its own src folder in order to implement Cross Program Invocation i.e importing the first program (pda.so) or crate in the same root. I believe locally it is possible using anchor init <program_name>.

Comment: What is your Anchor CLI version?

Comment: anchor-cli 0.25.0

Comment: A better place to ask is on their Github https://github.com/solana-playground/solana-playground

Comment: That version of Anchor uses an older version of Solana. Upgrade your Anchor CLI to 0.26.0 for it to be compatible with the current Solana mainnet/devnet versions.

Comment: so does anchor 0.26.0 support solana cli 1.10.29, coz thats what i have and i can only use solana 1.10.29 the other versions failed to install